# Round DateTime by a given DateTimeFieldType

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I use `org.joda.time`.

I have a `DateTime` and a `DateTimeFieldType` given.

What I want is to round my `DateTime` (up) to the nearest `DateTime` which is after mine, but with an integer number of the given field.

For example:

```
for (DateTime = 20/10/2013 14:20:31.200, DateTimeFiledType = DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth())
```

I will get: `21/10/2013 00:00:00.000`.

Did somebody do something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
DateTime.now().dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy()
```

or

```
DateTime.now().dayOfMonth().roundCeilingCopy()
```

Take a look at the [DateTime.Property class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html) for more information on this.

Edit:

As Krayo mentioned, you can pass the property directly as:

```
DateTime.now().property(DateTimeFieldType.secondOfDay()).roundFloorCopy();
```

Comment: Yes, the second line is the solution.